# One image pulled from Parse when there are actually two : weird error.

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have the following function that's suppose to pull images from a class in Parse. The number of images in the class is two and the print line `print(objectsFound?.count)` **prints out 2 - confirming there are two images**

```
func loadAllObjects() {
    let discoveryQuery = PFQuery(className: "DiscoveryDetails")
    discoveryQuery.cachePolicy = .NetworkElseCache
    discoveryQuery.whereKey("discoveryID", equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Discovery", objectId: "\(varInDDT!.objectId!)"))
    discoveryQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    discoveryQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objectsFound: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print(objectsFound?.count) //This prints out 2
            for var i = 0; i < objectsFound?.count; i++ {
                if let imageFileFound = objectsFound![i].objectForKey("workoutImage") as? PFFile {
                    imageFileFound.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil) {
                            self.arrayOfWorkoutImages = [UIImage(data:imageData!)!]
                        }
                    }                            
                }
            }
        } else {
            //An error Occured
            self.showFailureAlert(" Failed to get workout Images", detailedMessage: "Check your network settings and try again", buttonMessage: "Ok")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to load the images into an array where I can use them later. 
The line `self.arrayOfWorkoutImages = [UIImage(data:imageData!)!`] adds them to the array

```
var arrayOfWorkoutImages: [UIImage] = []
```

On trying to see whether the images are pulled (checking the `print(self.arrayOfWorkoutImages)` and print`(self.arrayOfWorkoutImages.count)` ) **I get only ONE image counted and pulled**. This is the function I am using that is linked to a button that does this.

```
@IBAction func addbuttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.loadAllObjects()
    print(self.arrayOfWorkoutImages)
    print(self.arrayOfWorkoutImages.count)
}
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong. This is has been throwing errors at me for a couple of days now!! :(

Comment: where do the error occurs?

Comment: I only get one image pulled from parse of two images that parse already says I have. Which is quite weird.

Comment: Maybe you read array before that 2 images have been downloaded, could be?

Comment: I actually think so too. Any ideas on how I can check when the images have been downloaded to then read the array?

Comment: take a look at the answer, you're doing a stupid error ,)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code contains an error: for each object you re-assign to `arrayOfWorkoutImages` an array with the retrieved image.

```
func loadAllObjects(completion: () -> Void) {
let discoveryQuery = PFQuery(className: "DiscoveryDetails")
    discoveryQuery.cachePolicy = .NetworkElseCache
    discoveryQuery.whereKey("discoveryID", equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Discovery", objectId: "\(varInDDT!.objectId!)"))
    discoveryQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    discoveryQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objectsFound: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for var i = 0; i < objectsFound?.count; i++ {
                if let imageFileFound = objectsFound![i].objectForKey("workoutImage") as? PFFile {
                    imageFileFound.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil) {
                           if let data = imageData, image = UIImage(data: data) {
                              self.arrayOfWorkoutImages.append(image)  
                           }
                        }
                    }                            
                }
            }
        }
       completion()
    }
}
```

Comment: Arghhh a completion block. Nice. And that was definitely a silly error. Thanks for your help. ;)